# celery feature "reply_to" don't works as expected

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I need configue to which queue celery should put result of task execution, I am using this way as [described in documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/3.1/userguide/tasks.html#context) (item "reply_to"):

```
@app.task(reply_to='export_task')  # <= configured right way
def test_func():
    return "here is result of task"
```

**Expected behavior**

Task result should be in queue with name "export_task" (as configured in decorator)

**Actual behavior**

Task result locates in queue with name like:
d5587446-0149-3133-a3ed-d9a297d52a96

---

**celery report:**

```
python -m celery -A my_worker report

software -> celery:3.1.24 (Cipater) kombu:3.0.37 py:3.5.1
            billiard:3.3.0.23 py-amqp:1.4.9
platform -> system:Windows arch:64bit, WindowsPE imp:CPython
loader   -> celery.loaders.app.AppLoader
settings -> transport:amqp results:rpc:///

CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT: ['json']
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND: 'rpc:///'
CELERY_QUEUES:
    (<unbound Queue main_check -> <unbound Exchange main_check(direct)> -> main_check>,)
CELERYD_CONCURRENCY: 10
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER: 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_PERSISTENT: True
CELERY_ROUTES: {
 'my_worker.test_func': {'queue': 'main_check'}}
BROKER_TRANSPORT: 'amqp'
CELERYD_MAX_TASKS_PER_CHILD: 3
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER: 'json'
```

---

**Steps to reproduce**

Please create files of project.

*celery_app.py*:

```
from celery import Celery
from kombu import Exchange, Queue

app = Celery('worker')

app.conf.update(
    CELERY_ROUTES={
        'my_worker.test_func': {'queue': 'main_check'},
    },
    BROKER_TRANSPORT='amqp',
    CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND='rpc://',
    CELERY_RESULT_PERSISTENT=True,
    # CELERY_DEFAULT_DELIVERY_MODE='persistent',
    # CELERY_RESULT_EXCHANGE='export_task',
    CELERYD_CONCURRENCY=10,
    CELERYD_MAX_TASKS_PER_CHILD=3,
    CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER='json',
    CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER='json',
    CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT=['json'],

    CELERY_QUEUES=(
        Queue('main_check', Exchange('main_check', type='direct'), routing_key='main_check'),
    ),
)
```

my_worker.py:

```
from celery_app import app

@app.task(reply_to='export_task')
def test_func():
    return "here is result of task"
```

then start celery:

```
python -m celery -A my_worker worker --loglevel=info
```

then in python debug console add new task:

```
from my_worker import *
result = test_func.delay()
```

I asked to help on [official issue tracker](https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3848), but nobody cares.

Comment: yep. if you are interesting I hired one guy who solved problem in a part, here in the end of thread https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3848

Comment: Have the same issue. It did not fixed yet... Did you solve this problem?

Comment: @SebastianWozny - as you know, it is an opensource project, so if there is something in the documentation you do not like, by all means submit a PR!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see in your code where that queue (export_task) has been declared.

Comment: it changes nothing, I checked. please read end of this thread to see more: https://github.com/celery/celery/issues/3848